# How can I automate a custom script (e.g. bash) each times when a file is downloaded?

Tags: macos, automation, safari, automator

I'm using Safari. However, some non-ascii filenames break when downloaded.

I want to automatically execute a bash / apple script each time when a file is downloaded.

The trigger I want is:

1. When a file is downloaded by Safari (most preferable)
2. When a file is added into ~/Downloades (possible using custom programs like watchdog or something else, but not that preferable)

I want the script to be triggered anytime without user interaction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first option you can create a Safari Extension with browser.downloads API.

For the second one, you just can create a "Folder action" using Automator.